# Using C++ access modifiers for one member only

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to make generating setters and getters in c++ more convenient. Now, I came up with this:

```
#define getterAndSetter(t, vn, fn) \
    t vn; \
    t get##fn() { \
        return vn; \
    } \
    void set##fn(t val) { \
        vn = val; \
    }
```

So, the problem is that now I have the variable and the getter in the same access (public/private). I could have written public: and private: there, but with that I lose context for the code that goes before and after these. The question is can I get access modifiers for only one member, like in Java?

Comment: I would say remove the setters and getters because it doesn't sound like there is any good reason to have them, if all they do is get and set data members.

Comment: If you are actually going to use this, your class design is bad. Either your data has invariants, then those set/get-thingies don't do the job, or it doesn't, then use an aggregate. If you have some of both, you class is too big and violates the Single Responsibility Principle. (As always, unless you have a weird special case where it makes sense. But you most likely don't.)

Comment: I mean, of course, I wouldn't use the code exactly like that, I need the setter to check the value before setting, but I have found that the class I use has too much fields, and it maybe actually violates the Single Responsibility Principle. Anyway, thanks

Comment: Why use macros? Type in the code! It is boiler plate stuff and explicit. Macros are hard to debug and not type safe.

Comment: That's just a very, very bad idea. You should rarely have a member variable with a direct getter and a direct setter; you may as well make the variable `public` then, it will make little difference.

Comment: If you want to make generating setters and getters more convenient (which shouldn't as others have noted, be that common in the first place), why don't you use an IDE? Eclipse will happily auto generate stubs for setters and getters.

Comment: the real design flaw is C++ access specifiers. If they were scopes rather than labels, this would be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. C++ makes that context-dependent. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't use macros. Then you could put everything in whatever access you want. Even ones that make no sense:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    T var;
private:
    T getVar() { return var; }
protected:
    void setVar(const T& v) { var = v; }
};
```

The further advantage is that everyone reading what I just wrote will understand what it does pretty quickly. With the macro, you're obfuscating and unreasonably complicating what should be simple code.

Comment: I agree - +1 - Just avoid macros as they are bad news

Comment: If I add a access modifier in front of every class member and method in the same line, is there any disadvantage?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, and I'm not happy in providing some working code that is broken in design.

First of all, using macros for doing such work is really a bad Idea, if you really want a macro try the following code(and default to private when you exit wich is the safest behaviour, assuming using macros is safe ^^):

```
#define MyMacroProperty(t, fn, visibilitygetter, visibilitysetter) \
    visibilitygetter :         \
    t get##fn() {              \
        return _##fn;          \
    }                          \
    visibilitysetter:          \
    void set##fn(t val) {      \
    _##fn = val;               \
    }                          \
    private:                   \
    t _##fn;
```

example

```
class Foo{
    MyMacroProperty(int, foo, public, protected);

public:

    Foo(): _foo(3) {}
};
```

Note that this is flawed in various ways:
You cannot plug additional logic inside the property (basically it is just setting/returning the value). The only case in wich make sense may be making a public/protected setter and a private getter (it just save some typing ) is outweighted by the fact you are using a macro, wich is text replacement.

However if you really want something like properties in C++ you can do that using templates (requires non trivial skill in C++):
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3900/Implementing-Properties-In-C

In that way you can at least have the chance to plug additional logic with functors (ankward syntax, just write manually the getter and setter). Basically setters/getters are syntactic sugar, and hence if the compiler cannot do that for you, it is counter-productive  trying to cheat.

From:
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

> Don’t use macros to create your own personal programming language.